# How to set schema field value as document _id value in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

if i have a schema called stores with the properties

```
{
storeid: ???,
Address: String,
Phone: Number
}
```

ect...

how do i set the storeid's value to equal the _id value of that same schema so that they are duplicates?

The only idea I have is to go back and set the storeid value manually after creating a new store but I am hoping there is a way to do this when the document is being created.

Comment: _id is unique so you can't do it

Comment: Have you looked at defining `storeid` as a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) property with the same value as `_id`?

Comment: virtuals actually looks like a solution. I will try that.